# Как перевести из Blob в BZ2 ? (Firebird и Java)

Tags: java, sql, firebird, blob

Нужно считать файл, хранящийся в формате blob из базы данных firebird (Сам файл является архивом в формате bz2). Испробовал уже кучу вариантов, не могу понять в чем ошибка.

SQL запрос:

Раньше было так:

```
String query = "Select FILENAME, DOKUMENTDATA from KONTAKTDOKUMENT " +
                    "where KONTAKTDOKUMENTARTID=11 AND KONTAKTDOKUMENTID=" + kunde.getId() + ";";
```

Теперь исправил на такое:

```
String query = "Select FILENAME, cast(DOKUMENTDATA as BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT) DOC  from KONTAKTDOKUMENT " +
                    "where KONTAKTDOKUMENTARTID=11 AND KONTAKTDOKUMENTID=" + kunde.getId() + ";";
```

Дальше читаю и обрабатываю так:

```
                    InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream(2);
                    String str = convert(is);
                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    File file = new File("E:\\Study\\alfresco\\zip", fileName + ".pdf.bz2");
                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    outputStream.write(str.getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
```

Метод convert:

```
private static String convert(InputStream is) {
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int result;
    String str = null;
    try {
        result = bis.read();

        while (result != -1) {
            buf.write((byte) result);
            result = bis.read();
        }
        str = buf.toString("iso-8859-1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}
```

Один из вариантов, что ошибка в кодировке (Но когда исправил на iso-8859-1 имена файлов стали нормально читаться, а вот сам архив - нет , пишет, что повреждена контрольная сумма)

Эту строку уже пробовал в различных вариациях и комбинациях (utf-8, iso-8859-1, ISO8859_1 ) .

```
str = buf.toString("iso-8859-1");
```

Сейчас подключаюсь к бд так, но пробовал и через юникод

```
?encoding=ISO8859_1;characterEncoding=ISO8859_1
```

Comment: `cast(DOKUMENTDATA as BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT)` - этого точно ненужно. У bz2 должен быть BLOB SUB_TYP BINARY. И ниже у вас зачем-то конвертация в текст. Этого тоже не нужно. Вам нужно бинарный поток данных сохранить в бинарный файл.

Comment: Не вижу собственно кода чтения самого BLOBa... - запрос есть, а как читаете значения поля?

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло